# Поворот image в Xamarin Forms

Tags: изображения, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Всем добрый день, как я могу повернуть Image в  Xamarin Forms, с дальнейшем сохранением в виде массива байтов? Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Гуглить то пробовали ? из первых строк поисковика [например](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading) я думаю можно найти и более простые решения, если вам только вращение. Вдогонку на том же стеке https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46435528/360-degree-image-rotating-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: @PavelPopov я гуглил целый день данный вопрос, ссылка на stackoverflow, которую вы прикрепили, никак не связана с моим вопросом. Там речь идёт об анимации, а мне же нужно повернуть фото и после этого сохранить его в виде массива байтов. Плагин Xamarin.FFImageLoading, так же не может справиться с данной задачей.